# User created switch option?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Is it possible to write a user-created switch case option? For example, if I had:

```
 String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name."
 switch (name) {
     case "Adam":
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is Adam";
     case "Julie":
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is Julie";
```

I want to write a program where, when the program prompts the user for a name, if the name is not one of the cases listed, the program will create a new case for it with the exact same executed code for each case. Is this possible?

Comment: Basically, no.  You have to take a different approach.

Comment: "*with the exact same executed code for each case*" What? Mind giving some kind of example of what you want?

Comment: You could use a `default:` case that uses `"Your name is "+name`. Note that you will need `break;` statements to stop each `case` from flowing into the next.

Comment: Basically, for each case, I'm going to have it execute the same code. However, if the case isn't one that is listed, I want the user to be able to create a new case, one with the exact same code under it as the other cases. Is this possible?

Comment: If it's EXACTLY the same code, then simply do it once for ANY case. If the code changes a small amount based on `name` entered, just using the variable in the code to be executed is the best option. (Perhaps you could provide a better example so we can tailor our answers more accurately)

Answer (score 1):

No, but you wouldn't want to do it like this either. There are so many names in the world! I hear someone in Australia actually tried to name their kid *'Batman'*. Do you really want to update your software for these guys?

You can skip the branching `switch` statement and just embed the name data programmatically.

```
public static final String getHelloString(final String pUserName) {
    return "Hello "+pUserName+"!";
}
```

Comment: It's the name that kid deserves, but not the one it needs right now. So we'll programmatically deal with it. Because it can take it. Because it's not a string constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output "Your name is `name`", then that's fairly easy to accomplish.

Simply do

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name.");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is " + name);
```

If you want to keep the `switch`, then do as @stvcisco suggested (in his comment) and make a `default` case:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name.");
switch (name) {
 case "Adam":
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is Adam");
     break;
 case "Julie":
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is Julie");
     break;
 default:
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is " + name);
     break; //This break is technically optional, but always a good idea anyways
}
```

The benefits of this option is it gives you the flexibility to have unique outputs for names you recognize along with a standard response for names you do not recognize.